# android lazy image loader cannot load http urls

Tags: android, http, android-arrayadapter, image-loading

i am using lazy image loader for loading images into my listview.
for some reason, the image loader dont load part of the images.
i think its because at the beginning of the address there is "http" and not "https".
so i tried to add "s" to "http" urls and for some of them it worked, but not for everyone.
there is a problam with "http" in lazy image loader?
if there is, what do i have to do?

**Adapter**

```
else if(type.contains("link")){                         //LINK
        holder.largeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.linkDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        loader.DisplayImage(holder.feed.getLinkThumbnail(), holder.largeImage);

        holder.linkDescription.setText(holder.feed.getLinkDescription());
        holder.linkTitle.setText(holder.feed.getLinkTitle());


        holder.largeImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                linkUrl(holder.feed.getPostUrl());
            }
        });
    }
```

**ImageLoader/DisplayImage**

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

    if(url.subSequence(0, 5).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("https") == false){
        if(url.subSequence(0, 4).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("http"))
            url = url.replaceFirst("http", "https");
    }

    imageViews.put(imageView, url);

    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

    if (bitmap != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }

}
```